# The name of the mountain - "Revelation, 21,10"?

Tags: revelation

Elischa on the moutain, "2 Kings 4,27" - but what is the name of the mountain of "Revelation 21,10"? E, "Siegfried Posch"

> And he carried me away in the spirit to a great and high mountain, and shewed me that great city, the holy Jerusalem, descending out of heaven from God, [Revelation 21:10 KJV]

Comment: The mountain is not named in the narrative of the vision. One therefore assumes it is a figurative mountain, not a physical mountain on earth : one seen in vision as representative of spiritual truth. Please see the Tour and the Help (below, bottom left) as to the purpose and functioning of the site. Welcome to BH.

Comment: Cf. Mt 4:8/Lk 4:5.

Answer (score 2):

After the seven cups of the wrath of God are poured out on the earth, the way is clear for the revelation of the bride, the Lamb’s wife. ***John is carried away in the spirit*** to a great and high mountain, and sees the holy Jerusalem descending out of heaven from God (Revelation 21:9-10).

This vision is after the end of the present age.  John has been carried away in the spirit to see this wonderful vision.

> The vision must be spiritual, not natural.  Therefore it must be spiritually interpreted.  Then, what is signified by the great and high mountain?

> Used allegorically, in general mountains signify two great truths.  First, they are indicative of the meeting place between heaven and earth.  Of himself, man can ascend to heaven no higher: it is naturally the nearest to the most High that he can ascend.  Conversely, mountains figure the first place reached on earth in the descent of God from heaven (Psalm 114:5).  Both covenants, old and new, called for the ascent of mount Sinai and spiritual mount Zion respectively, by each Apostle and Mediator in order, or ever God handed down the testament to be promulgated among men far below...

> Since ‘Behold, the tabernacle of God is with men, and he will dwell with them’, Revelation 21:3, the first truth of the mountain, the meeting place of heaven and earth, God and man, is in this place more than fulfilled.  So is the second, the view of all the earth below from the elevation of so great a height above.  From such an eminence as this great and high mountain, ***spiritually John perceived everything that was of God in heaven now descending to be established for ever on the earth below.  The new earth.***  Thus the earth shall be filled with the glory of God as once the waters covered the sea.

Source: The Revelation of Jesus Christ by John Metcalfe – The Seventh Opening, pp 588 – 590

The Revelation does not disclose the name of this holy mountain.  I agree with this comment:

> ***It is a figurative mountain, not a physical mountain on earth: one seen in vision as representative of spiritual truth.***

Answer (score 0):

It has two possible names, depending on whether we speak of *before* or *after* the New Jerusalem has settled upon it: The Mount of Olives, or Mount Zion.

Before the Holy City comes down to it, the mountain is known as the Mount of Olives.

> And his feet shall stand in that day upon the mount of Olives, which
> is before Jerusalem on the east, and the mount of Olives shall cleave
> in the midst thereof toward the east and toward the west, and there
> shall be a very great valley; and half of the mountain shall remove
> toward the north, and half of it toward the south. . . . And it shall
> be in that day, that living waters shall go out from Jerusalem; half
> of them toward the former sea, and half of them toward the hinder sea:
> in summer and in winter shall it be.  And the LORD shall be king over
> all the earth: in that day shall there be one LORD, and his name one.
> . . . And men shall dwell in it, and there shall be no more utter
> destruction; but Jerusalem shall be safely inhabited. (Zechariah
> 14:4,8-9, 11)

Afterward, however, the place is called Mount Zion (which is incorrectly spelled Sion in some translations, e.g. KJV).

> But ye are come unto mount Sion, and unto the city of the living God,
> the heavenly Jerusalem, and to an innumerable company of angels,
> (Hebrews 12:22)
>
> And I looked, and, lo, a Lamb stood on the mount Sion, and with him an
> hundred forty and four thousand, having his Father's name written in
> their foreheads. (Revelation 14:1)

Answer (score 0):

In the book of Revelation, the word, "mountain" only occurs eight times as follows:

- Rev 6:14, 15, 16 - mountains vanish and the wicked ask to be destroyed by them
- Rev 8:8 - a burning mountain that appears to allude to Ex 19 and Heb 12:18, ie, Mt Sinai
- Rev 14:1 - Mt Zion
- Rev 16:20 - mountains moved
- Rev 17:9 - seven mountains of Babylon
- Rev 21:10 - great mountain associated with the New Jerusalem.  This appears to allude to Mt Zion.

There is one more in Rev 16:16 - "Harmageddon" = Mt Megiddo.  But this is another matter.  The mountain in Rev 21:10 appears to allude to Mt Zion.